# How do I use an existing dataset in a PySpark test in Palantir Foundry code repository?

Tags: pyspark, pytest, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories

I am writing a PySpark / PyTest test where I would like to use a dataset that already exists within Palantir Foundry alongside created test data.  However when I make the dataset available to the test function using the `@transform` decorator it no longer recognises the function as a test meaning it will not run as part of the test suite.

Here is an example of two test functions, which would be in a file named something like `myproject/test/test_scoring.py`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from transforms.api import Input, transform
from myproject.datasets.scoring import red_rag_to_amber
from myproject.datasets.scoring import compute
from datetime import date

@transform(
    weightings_df=Input("ri.foundry.main.dataset.2c963320-1e49-4201-Z921-dce333124999"),
)
def test_compute(spark_session, weightings_df):
    source_df_schema = T.StructType([
        T.StructField("metric", T.StringType(), False),
        T.StructField("reason", T.StringType(), True),
        T.StructField("date", T.DateType(), False),
        T.StructField("value", T.IntegerType(), True),
    ])

    source_df_data = [
        ["1_X_Y", "Not measured", date.fromisoformat("2021-08-01"), 100],
        ["1_A_B", "Not measured", date.fromisoformat("2021-08-01"), 100],
    ]
    source_df = spark_session.createDataFrame(source_df_data, source_df_schema)
    df = compute(source_df, weightings_df)
    result = df.collect()  # noqa
    assert result[0].score == "amber"

def test_red_to_amber(spark_session):
    schema = T.StructType([
        T.StructField("metric", T.StringType(), False),
        T.StructField("date", T.DateType(), False),
        T.StructField("score", T.StringType(), True),
    ])
    data = [
        ["4_X_Y", date.fromisoformat("2021-12-01"), "red"],
    ]
    df = spark_session.createDataFrame(data, schema)
    df = red_rag_to_amber(df)
    result = df.collect()  # noqa
    assert result[0].score == "amber"
```

In the above, function `test_red_to_amber` works perfectly.  As the image below demonstrates a small blue triangle appears to the left of the line number corresponding to the function name within the Palantir Foundry IDE:

[image: Test able to run]

This means one can run the PySpark test by selecting the blue arrow.

However `test_compute` is not recognised as a test function.  As shown in the below image, there is no blue triangle therefore no ability to run as a test:

[image: A function that can't be tested]

(NB - Please ignore the Restricted resource warning, the RID shown is a dummy one due to my organisation's policy on sharing data externally)

Removing the `@transform` decorator means that the dataset is not imported to the test function, but it is recognised as a test.  The image below demonstrates this:

[image: Testable function]

Although I could now run the test by selecting the blue arrow; the existing `weightings_df` dataset will not be imported as an argument because the `@transform` decorator which tells the function that there is a corresponding RID is no longer present.

The question therefore is how can I run the function as a test whilst continuing to import an existing dataset as an argument to the test?

NB - For what it is worth I think the answer is you can't.  There is no way to import an existing dataset into a test function, you simply have to create all the data within the function itself.  Delighted to be proved wrong however.

Answer (score 0):

Showing an error message will be really helpful to find out actually failure cause.

Recommendations: Based on the information provided in thread & looking at the code.

- For Code Repositories transformations, you have to include a
  parameter **ctx** which gives you more access to the underlying
  infrastructure running your job. Typically, you'll access the
  ctx.spark_session attribute for making your own pyspark.sql.Dataframe
  objects from Python objects.
- Additionally you have to explicitly use write_dataframe() for your
  input(weightings_df) as in transform decorator we have to explicitly define what
  type of input.

proposed changes below:

```
@transform(
    weightings_df=Input("ri.foundry.main.dataset.2c963320-1e49-4201-Z921- 
    dce333124999")
          )
def test_compute(ctx, weightings_df):
    source_df_schema = T.StructType([
        T.StructField("metric", T.StringType(), False),
        T.StructField("reason", T.StringType(), True),
        T.StructField("date", T.DateType(), False),
        T.StructField("value", T.IntegerType(), True),
    ])

    source_df_data = [
        ["1_X_Y", "Not measured", date.fromisoformat("2021-08-01"), 
        100],
        ["1_A_B", "Not measured", date.fromisoformat("2021-08-01"), 
        100],
    ]
    source_df = ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame(source_df_data, 
                                                  source_df_schema)
    weightings_df = weightings_df.dataframe()
    df = compute(source_df, weightings_df)
    result = df.collect()  # noqa
    assert result[0].score == "amber"

def test_red_to_amber(ctx):
    schema = T.StructType([
        T.StructField("metric", T.StringType(), False),
        T.StructField("date", T.DateType(), False),
        T.StructField("score", T.StringType(), True),
    ])
    data = [
             ["4_X_Y", date.fromisoformat("2021-12-01"), "red"],
           ]
    df = ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame(data, schema)
    df = red_rag_to_amber(df)
    result = df.collect()  # noqa
    assert result[0].score == "amber"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and feedback.  I have edited the question by adding images which hopefully provide more context on the problem.